# Do I want most regular views to be converted to tastypie APIs?

Tags: django, rest, tastypie, django-rest-framework

I'm converting regular django views to tastypie apis.
(My question is not specific to tastypie, using any rest-framework would have raised the same question)

I see people use tastypie even for logging in a user.
[How can I login to django using tastypie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770501/how-can-i-login-to-django-using-tastypie)

I guess you could use tastypie to upload an image to a gallery-app and so on.

I guess since tastypie is used to `handle resource`, `uploading an image` can be thought as `creating a resource`.
I don't see how `login` could be considered as `handling resource`.
(it's non of CRUD as I see it)

The question is, what is the line that I should draw between `regular views` and `tastypie powered views`.
When do you use regular views and when do you use tastypie or other rest-api powered views?

Comment: It is easy to conceive of login/authentication as managing a resource if you think about the session that backs it. Consider POST /login as shorthand for POST /session, where a new session is created and often a record added to the backing store. Then you also have DELETE /session aliased as /logout.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the fact that logging an user in can not be considered as a handling a resource.

However, the real question is what would be the easiest and most intuitive way to do it ? What would be the benefits of doing it in your REST framework instead of doing it in a standard view ?

In this case, I'd rather go with a regular view.