# Loging in a user with tastypie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I followed this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770501/how-can-i-login-to-django-using-tastypie) because i want to add login with tastypie for my django app. I did the necessary corrections because of deprecated methods and ran it. The logout process works as it should. But i get an error in the login page.

```
expected string or buffer
```

and a 500 status code. The error comes when i try to desirialize the posted data. The login view is the following

```
 def login(self, request, **kwargs):
    self.method_check(request, allowed=['post',])
    try:
        data = self.deserialize(request, HttpRequest.body, format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))
    except BaseException as e:
        print e

    username = data.get('username', '')
    password = data.get('password', '')
    print username, password

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user:
        if user.is_active:
            print 'Before login'
            login(request, user)
            return self.create_response(request, {
                'success': True
            })
        else:
            return self.create_response(request, {
                'success': False,
                'reason': 'disabled',
                }, HttpForbidden )
    else:
        return self.create_response(request, {
            'success': False,
            'reason': 'incorrect',
            }, HttpUnauthorized )
```

I used python requests to post the data for testing

```
data = {'username':'user', 'password':'pass}
parmas = json.dumps(data)
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
resp = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/user/login/', data=params, headers=headers)
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: Can you show us the traceback?

Comment: You've misspelled params on line 2.

Comment: I use them correctly on my code, typo there. But it worked when i changed my url in to 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/user/login/?format=json'. I don't know if the original post didn't mention it because it is taken for granted, but it worked now. Thank you

Comment: Agrhhh...Now the logout method from the same example will always see me as AnonymousUser when trying to logout from python using requests. Why is that now....It's like Hydra...You fix one and 2 more come out...

Comment: fixxed it!!!: I got my sessionid cookie from the login response, and send it with every request.get() using the cookies. Works like a charm