# Django: set session via Ajax

Tags: ajax, django

I'm trying to make an Ajax login form. I can get the user authenticated with `django.contrib.auth.authenticate` by passing it the username and password coming from the ajax post. But how can I them set an actual session and csrf so that in subsequent calls I can get the user in request.user?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `{% csrf_token %}` as normal then add a pre-request callback function [beforeSend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) on your AJAX POST etc:

```
  beforeSend: function (request) {
   request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken",
       $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val());
   },
```

If using an API Framework like [TastyPie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) you have other options for authentication. See here: [How can I login to django using tastypie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770501/how-can-i-login-to-django-using-tastypie)