# User managment django-tastypie (angular)

Tags: django, angularjs, tastypie

Okey so I wish to create really simple user managment for my site using django(1.6), tastyie and angularjs. I want to be able to signin/up/out. I have basically implemented the solution from here: [How can I login to django using tastypie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770501/how-can-i-login-to-django-using-tastypie)

my code looks like this:

resources:

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource, ALL, ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
from photod.models import Project, ProjectImage
from tastypie.authorization import DjangoAuthorization,Authorization
from tastypie.authentication import BasicAuthentication,Authentication
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from tastypie import fields
from tastypie.serializers import Serializer
from tastypie.exceptions import BadRequest
from django.db import IntegrityError
from tastypie.http import HttpUnauthorized, HttpForbidden
from django.conf.urls import url
from tastypie.utils import trailing_slash

class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'user'
        excludes = ['email', 'password', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser'] 
        serializer = Serializer(formats=['json', 'jsonp'])
        always_return_data = True
        filtering = {
            'username': 'exact',
            'id': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
        }

    def prepend_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/login%s$" %
                (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
                self.wrap_view('login'), name="api_login"),
            url(r'^(?P<resource_name>%s)/logout%s$' %
                (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
                self.wrap_view('logout'), name='api_logout'),
        ]

    def login(self, request, **kwargs):
        self.method_check(request, allowed=['post'])
        data = self.deserialize(request, request.body, format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))
        username = data.get('username', '')
        password = data.get('password', '')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return self.create_response(request, {
                    'success': True
                })
            else:
                return self.create_response(request, {
                    'success': False,
                    'reason': 'disabled',
                    }, HttpForbidden )
        else:
            return self.create_response(request, {
                'success': False,
                'reason': 'incorrect user information',
                }, HttpUnauthorized )

    def logout(self, request, **kwargs):
        self.method_check(request, allowed=['get'])
        if request.user and request.user.is_authenticated():
            logout(request)
            return self.create_response(request, { 'success': True })
        else:
            return self.create_response(request, { 'success': False }, HttpUnauthorized)

lass CreateUserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        allowed_methods = ['post']
        object_class = User
        resource_name = 'register'
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
        include_resource_uri = False
        fields = ['username', 'id']
        always_return_data = True
    def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
        username, password = bundle.data['username'], bundle.data['password']
        try:
            bundle.obj = User.objects.create_user(username, '', password)
        except IntegrityError:
            raise BadRequest('That username already exists')
        return bundle
```

front end:

```
photodice.controller('userController', function($scope, $resource, userFactory) {
  $scope.userName = '';
  $scope.userPw = '';
  $scope.Signup = function() {
   var userC = $resource("http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx/api/v1/register/");
   var newUser = new userC();
   newUser.username = $scope.userName;
   newUser.password =  $scope.userPw;
   newUser.$save(function (user, headers) {// Success
    userFactory.setUser(user.username, user.id);
    console.log("$save (signUp) success " + JSON.stringify(user));
    $scope.userName = '';//cleanup
    $scope.userPw = '';//cleanup
   }, function (error) {// failure - TODO: add message
    console.log("$save (signUp) failed " + JSON.stringify(error.data.error_message))
   });
  }
$scope.Signin = function() {
var userResource = $resource('http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx/api/v1/user/login/');
user = new userResource();
user.username = $scope.userName;
user.password = $scope.userPw;
user.$save(function () {// Success
  userFactory.setUser($scope.userName);
  console.log("$save (signIn) success " + JSON.stringify(user));
  $scope.userName = '';//cleanup
  $scope.userPw = '';//cleanup
}, function (error) {// failure - TODO: add message
  console.log("$save (signIn) failed " + JSON.stringify(error.data.error_message));
});
}
$scope.Signout = function() {
console.log("called signout");
var userResource = $resource('http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx/api/v1/user/logout/:user', { user:'@user' });
var user = userResource({user:userFactory.getUser()}, function() {
user.$save(function (user, headers) {// Success
  userFactory.setUser('');
  console.log("$save (signIn) success " + JSON.stringify(user));
}, function (error) {// failure - TODO: add message
  console.log("$save (signIn) failed " + JSON.stringify(error.data.error_message));
});
});
}
});
```

But I have some problems and questions:
Firstly I can sign in with the superuser account, but i only get {"success":true,"$resolved":true} as respons... should i not get some sort of token or id or more data?

Secoundly i can signup new users, but they can NOT sign in as i get: 401 (UNAUTHORIZED)

Edit: upon further investigation i notised that although I can sign up new users, thay do not get any password set... why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1

> But I have some problems and questions: Firstly I can sign in with the
>   superuser account, but i only get {"success":true,"$resolved":true} as
>   respons... should i not get some sort of token or id or more data?

What you do in login is assigning request with user. You authenticated user here: `user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)` and assigned that user to request here: `login(request, user)`. So Django will now recognize `request.user` as that user during your session.

You haven't defined authentication method in your resource therefore is default. It gives access to anonymous users also so don't have to be even authenticated to have access. Once your decide which authentication you want to use then you will think about tokens and stuff.
See this: [Authentication in Tastypie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication.html#authentication-options)

### 2

> Secoundly i can signup new users, but they can NOT sign in as i get:
>   401 (UNAUTHORIZED)

Your are seeing this most likely because your password or username is incorrect. `user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)` gives you `user is None` and your `eles` block is executed. You can make sure with printing logs in that step.

### 3

> Edit: upon further investigation i notised that although I can sign up
>   new users, thay do not get any password set... why is this?

I tested the same code and works perfectly. Make sure you don't have typo on frontend side. And print logs with values in `obj_create` to make sure they aren't empty.

### 4

To allow session authentication is quite difficult and it is capable for another question. This make it possible to get `request.user`. (Very insecure but simple)

```
class PasswordAuthentication(Authentication):
    def is_authenticated(self, request, **kwargs):
        """
        Allow get not authenticated users but try assign user to request
        if possible.
        """
        try:
            username, password = request.GET.get('username'), request.GET.get('password')
        except ValueError:
            return True

        if not username or not password:
            return True

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username, password=password)
        except (User.DoesNotExist, User.MultipleObjectsReturned):
            return True

        if not self.check_active(user):
            return True

        request.user = user

        return True


class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'user'
        excludes = ['email', 'password', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser'] 
        serializer = Serializer(formats=['json', 'jsonp'])
        authentication = PasswordAuthentication()
        always_return_data = True
        filtering = {
            'username': 'exact',
            'id': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
        }

    [...]

    def logout(self, request, **kwargs):
        self.method_check(request, allowed=['get'])
        if request.user and request.user.is_authenticated():
            logout(request)
            return self.create_response(request, { 'success': True })
        else:
            return self.create_response(request, { 'success': False }, HttpUnauthorized)
```

call backend with `http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx/api/v1/user/logout/4/?username=asdf&password=1234`

Comment: Thank you! dont rly know what i might have done, but i  re copied the "original" code from my post and now it works:) just one question, can i use request.user in the other resources?

Comment: Sure, you can use `request.user` as long as your browser session last.

Comment: one more question... what does "user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)" do? when i print the user throught the different function it is always "AnonymousUser". and becuse of that request.user.is_authenticated() in logout will be false...

Comment: @BAYELK Yes your correct. You see, probably you don't attach required meta data to requests on Angular side. So Django don't picks it from request and don't assign. If I get more time I will try to make some tests to make sure. I update answer.