# Android Volley Login with Tastypie Django

Tags: android, python, django, android-volley, tastypie

Till now I have made a django custom user and I already know how to get response using Volley's Request.Method.GET
Now I want to make Volley's Request.Method.POST for checking login in django user which is giving me an error which I cannot understand
I have tried this on Emulator

Here is my code of Android Client application which contains Volley Request

```
private TextView mUsername, mPassowrd;
private Button mLogin;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private String url;
private String username;
private String password;
public static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.1.107:8000/api/myuser/login";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    mUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
    mPassowrd = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.password);
    mLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);

    mLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            userLogin();
        }
    });

}

private void userLogin() {
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    username = mUsername.getText().toString().trim();
    password = mPassowrd.getText().toString().trim();

    JsonObjectRequest stringRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_URL,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    String toast;
                    if(response.toString().trim().equals("success"))
                        toast = "Success";
                    else
                        toast = "Faliure";
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,toast,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError{
            Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
            map.put("username",username);
            map.put("password",password);
            return map;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}
```

Here is my code for django api

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from myauth.models import MyUser
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from tastypie.http import HttpUnauthorized,HttpForbidden
from django.conf.urls import url
from tastypie.utils import trailing_slash


class MyUserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = MyUser.objects.all()
        fields =['username','first_name','last_name','email']
        allowed_methods = ['get','post']
        resource_name = 'myuser'

    def override_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/login%s$" %
                (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
                self.wrap_view('login'), name="api_login"),

            url(r'^(?P<resource_name>%s)/logout%s$' %
                (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
                self.wrap_view('logout'), name='api_logout'),
        ]


    def login(self, request, **kwargs):
        self.method_check(request,allowed=['post'])
        data = self.deserialize(request, request.raw_post_data,       format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))

        username = data.get('username','')
        password = data.get('password','')

        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)

        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request,user)
                return self.create_response(request,{
                    'success': True
                })
            else:
                 return self.create_response(request,{
                    'success': False,
                    'reason': 'disabled',
                }, HttpForbidden)
        else:
             return self.create_response(request, {
                'success': False,
                'reason': 'incorrect',
             }, HttpUnauthorized)
```

Here is the error which I get

```
10-08 12:22:27.009   2139-14933/com.example.root.mylogin E/Volley﹕ [131]      BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for   http://192.168.1.107:8000/api/myuser/login
10-08 12:22:27.155    2139-2158/com.example.root.mylogin W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-08 12:22:27.155    2139-2158/com.example.root.mylogin W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa2685120, error=EGL_SUCCESS
10-08 12:22:30.533    2139-2158/com.example.root.mylogin E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab752750
```

I referred to this stackoverflow answer
[how-can-i-login-to-django-using-tastypie](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/11770501/how-can-i-login-to-django-using-tastypie)

Comment: Looks like you have control over the server app, so debug it to check why error. Moreover, you can use Postman add-in for Chrome to test with your server app first. When having the result, post screenshot for more info.

Comment: Django is giving you a 500 error. You should find out why.

Answer (score 0):

Use Custom_Volly_Request  for send parameters hopefully it will help you

```
private void userLogin() {
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    username = mUsername.getText().toString().trim();
    password = mPassowrd.getText().toString().trim();

    Custom_Volly_Request stringRequest = new Custom_Volly_Request (Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_URL,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    String toast;
                    if(response.toString().trim().equals("success"))
                        toast = "Success";
                    else
                        toast = "Faliure";
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,toast,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError{
            Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
            map.put("username",username);
            map.put("password",password);
            return map;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}
```

Custom_Volly_Request class :

```
import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.ParseError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener;
import com.android.volley.Response.Listener;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Map;


public class Custom_Volly_Request extends Request<JSONObject>
{

    private Listener<JSONObject> listener;
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public Custom_Volly_Request(String url, Map<String, String> params, Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.GET, url, errorListener);
        this.listener = reponseListener;
        this.params = params;
    }

    public Custom_Volly_Request(int method, String url, Map<String, String> params, Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        this.listener = reponseListener;
        this.params = params;
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
        return params;
    };

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {
        listener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String jsonString = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: this doesn't worked for me ! @Umar it gives the same error !